# Параллельность запросов в GO

Tags: многопоточность, postgresql, golang

Собираюсь написать приложение, которое будет работать с платежными системами(golang + postgresql). Мне не понятен один факт - как сделать так, чтобы обрабатывать несколько запросов одновременно, к примеру одновременно кто-то запрашивает таблицу на запись, чтение и т.д. Как организовать эти процессы? Я слышал, что golang как то, сам запускает обработку нескольких запросов в методе обработки ServeHTTP, и что реляционные базы сами организовывают это, правда ли? Если какая это информация, скиньте линк плз.

Answer (score 1):

Многопоточность реализована по умолчанию почти во всех пакетах для реализации сервера. Например пакет по умолчанию https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/